# Lista de formulários no projeto

Tags: c#

Preciso de uma `List<>` de todos os *Forms* no projeto c#, para ao iniciar o `exe` inserir no banco de dados o nome de todos os *Forms*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando *reflection* pode obter o nome de todas as classes do tipo *Form* desta forma:

```
IEnumerable<string> formNames = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                                where t.IsClass && 
                                      t.BaseType == typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Form)
                                select t.Name;
```

Adaptado [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18655359/2556111)